# headed or heading, started or starting?

Tags: meaning-in-context, verb-forms

Consider:

> Two units are ***headed*** your way.
> Two units are ***heading*** your way.
>
> Don't get me ***started***!
> Don't get me ***starting***!

Is there any difference in meaning?

And I don't see why passive voice is used here. I would think they have similar meaning here.

Help me to clarify!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Headed" can mean "pointed in a particular direction," so it suffices as a shorthand way of *implying* that those units are also *heading* that way. *Heading* is the active participle, equivalent to *moving*. Although the words are not *precisely* synonymous, they are used interchangeably because of the *implication* within the word *headed*. This is an example of the flexibility of the language.

The other sentences are different, because they are not referring to an ongoing process. "Heading your way" is an ongoing process of movement. "Don't get me started" means "don't cause me to HAVE BEGUN." *Starting* can't be used here because it is not an accomplished state. When you say, "don't get me started," you mean, "don't cause me to go from NOT doing something to DOING something." As in, "don't cause me to HAVE STARTED talking about that bridge that was built all wrong!" If you said, "don't get me starting," you would be saying, "don't get me into a state of continuously being IN THE PROCESS OF STARTING."

Comment: Thanks! i don't quite understand  "don't cause me to HAVE BEGUN." Let's say, my mom ask me to talk about my girlfriend, but i am not willing to. Can i say to my mom "don't get me started"? @John M. Landsberg

Comment: You COULD, but you wouldn't, because there is a special _tone_ to the phrase "don't get me started.* It implies, "I have a lot to say about how annoyed I am about this thing!" You don't say, "don't get me started!" when you only mean, "I just don't feel like talking right now; maybe later." (Well, except maybe you really are annoyed about your girlfriend!!)

Comment: "don't cause me to HAVE BEGUN." Why not "don't cause me to begin." You usually cause somebody to do sth, you cannot cause somebody to do sth which they already started. @John M. Landsberg

Comment: I'd go so far as to say "Don't get me started" is somewhat idiomatic, meaning "Don't get me started _on a rant_."

Comment: @ J.R.: I might go a little further and say that *"Don't get me started!"* is completely inappropriate as a response to Zhanlong's mother because it normally implies *I actually **do** want to talk about this [vociferously and at length] - but you really don't want to have to listen to me ranting on, so I advise you not to encourage me.*

Comment: I have watched Death Race before. The main actress did say that to the main actor. Your explanation is directly on point. @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Zhanlong: I keep a fair few movie subtitles on my PC because my father's getting a bit deaf in his 90s. If you're into film contexts, I can tell you *"Don't get me started"* also turns up in *Natural Born Killers (1994), Fear and Loathing in Las Vegas (1998)* and *Happy Go Lucky (2008)*. Always with the sense of ***you** don't/shouldn't want to get me started talking about that*.

Comment: Don't forget that "don't get me started!" is a common, well known, well accepted idiom. It has power and currency. It has a fully fleshed out, well-established, known meaning. In just a few words, it says this: "Oh, baby, let me tell you this: You just don't want to even give me a chance to start talking about THAT subject because WOW am I EVER going to give you a ranting earful of just how annoyed I am about it, and my diatribe isn't going to end for a LOOOOONG time!" So there. Why not "don't cause me to begin?" Because it's awkward and effete, and it's just not what we say.