# get with past participle

Tags: sentence-construction, participles

> Let's get started!

In this sentence "get started" means that "to begin or start".But as far as I know "get + v-ing" has that meaning too .Such as in the following examples :

> We have to get moving now.
>
> It's getting dark.

So can we use "get+past participle" to mean "to begin or start" ? or "get started" is just an exception ? I mean can I say

> I have to get written.

instead of

> I have to get writing.

Comment: *Get doing something* (= "get + v-ing") doesn't mean "begin or start". Where did you read that? A good portion of your post hinges on that false premise. Please see [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24853/3395) regarding the meaning and use of *Let's get started*.

Comment: @userr2684291   get doing something = to begin doing something:  _We got talking about the old days.  I think we should get going quite soon.  What are we all waiting for? Let’s get moving!_ Longman DOCE 5ed.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, "started" is a past perfect participle which effectively is an adjective,

> The program is **started**.

It seems to me you can use the "get + past perfect participle" with *any* verb where the past perfect participle is a similarly idiomatic adjective.

> We need to find a way to **get** them **motivated**.
>
> You'd better leave before you **get tired**.
>
> In the dark of the moonlight night the young explorers **got turned around** and didn't know where they were.

Or, more colloquially:

> Come on Willy.  Let's **get sloshed**!

The past perfect participle of "write" is "written", and it's perfectly fine to say something like:

> Let's **get** this (report) **written**.

in the same way you might say:

> Let's **get** this (project) **done**.

"Written" here is an *adjective* that describes the intended status of the report.

However you do have to be careful since the meaning of "written" can vary depending on context.  A "written report" is usually considered to be one that has been *written by hand* not one that is *completely finished*.  As usual, you have to know what is idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

get started, get finished:  Those are idiomatic.

Those mean: begin doing something or get through something, a task.

**But get plus a gerund** meaning to start has invaded other areas, too.

get writing, get studying, get moving, get going, get rolling, get dancing, [movement] **Get here means: start**, start writing, start studying, start going, get writing. It's often heard in AmE speech.

**Get** also means **become**: **get rich, get tired, get bored**, etc. Get is very complicated so I am limiting myself to those aspects.

Comment: The distinction between _gerund_ and _present participle_ being blurry in modern grammar notwithstanding, I'd still like to know why you think it is a _gerund_ instead of a participle that follows _get_.

Answer (score 0):

"Get started" is a fixed phrase. It seems you are troubled by the thought that in the sentence "Let's get started on the essay" *we* is the subject and the agent of the action, *the essay* the object and patient of the action. You are right to think that "start" here is a past participle.

It might be easier for you to understand its grammar structure this way: it is true people idiomatically say "get started", but "get" can also be used in the structure *get + object + past participle*:

> Let's get the job done tonight.
>
> I will get you started on the project.

"Start" as a transitive verb can be used with a person (sentient being) as the object. For example, you can say:

> The lecture started me thinking.

So such phrases as "get someone started" "get the work done" indeed imply passive voice. You can understand "let's get started" in a similar light. *Subject + get + past participle* means upon the subject an action is carried out. "He got dumped" means "he was dumped".

Think of it this way: in "get + past/present participle" the participle gives you a state. The subject of "get" will be put in/achieve that state through "get". For example, "He got tired" means *he* was put in the state of being tired. "It is getting dark" means *it* (the environment/sky) is reaching the state of being dark. By the same token, "I should get going" means *I* should reach the condition of moving.

Comment: Thanks, what about the last two sentences I wrote ?

Comment: @Lambie My answer doesn't exclude those. Plus, some of the comments have already addressed what you are saying.

Comment: @TalhaÖzden "I have to get written" makes little sense. "get writing", as pointed out in some comments, means _start writing_.